# Change the values of multiple checkboxes with React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hook-form

I created a form with properties which so far all work very well with **react hook form**. Only I have a little more difficulty implementing an array with **the different values of my checkboxes.**

I would like when submitting my form, instead of having an array of values with `true` or `false`, the values are replaced by the `label._id` which corresponds to the **id** of the **label**.

Also, I would like `false` values to not be pushed into my labels property.

I use the `Controller` wrapper to manage the *shadcn library* component :

```
import { Controller, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useQueryClient } from 'react-query';
import { Checkbox } from '@/components/ui/shadcn-ui/checkbox';

const LabelsOption = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const labels = queryClient.getQueryData(['labels']) || [];
    const {control} = useFormContext();

    return(
        <div className='relative'>
        
            <div className='absolute bg-neutral-50 z-2 flex flex-col gap-1 w-32 border rounded-md shadow-[rgba(0,_0,_0,_0.24)_0px_3px_8px] p-3'>
                {labels.map((label, index) => (
                    <div key={label._id}>
                        <Controller 
                            control={control}
                            name={`labels.${index}`}
                            render={({ field: { onChange, value, ref } }) => (
                                <Checkbox
                                    onCheckedChange={onChange}
                                    checked={value}
                                    value={label._id}
                                    ref={ref}
                                />
                            )}
                        />
                        <span className='ml-4'>{label.labelName}</span>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LabelsOption;
```

For example when I submit this selection:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n531C.png)

I have this result :

```
[
    true,
    true,
    true,
    null,
    null
]
```

While I would like to have an array of `label_ids` of my checkboxes`.

I thought about using `setValue` of `useForm` but the result was not conclusive.
By default, the checkbox values are true or false and I would like to change this with *react hook form*, how to do it?

Thanks a lot for your help

I thought about using setValue of useForm but the result was not conclusive. By default, the checkbox values are true or false and I would like to change this with react hook form, how to do it?